# Is there a reason YouTube no longer fully buffers?

Tags: youtube

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [YouTube stops buffering when video is paused](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/26213/youtube-stops-buffering-when-video-is-paused)

Ever since a month or two ago, YouTube videos seem to no longer pre-load (buffer) the entire video for me. It'll only buffer say 20% ahead of from where the current position is.

For example, [on this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uAjv3wN-QZc&feature=youtu.be) (3:25 length) I'm at 0:03 and it buffers to about 0:52 then stops buffering. This on Chrome, while logged into my account.

Now I open up the same video in Firefox while logged out, and with no cache... and it does the same thing (buffers until about 0:50). Or [this other video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-qY8s7X-f30) (6:04 length) for example under same conditions, position at 0:04 and it only buffers to 0:50. The first video tested with medium quality, and that last one with low quality.

Does YouTube no longer buffer the entire video?

Is there an official statement about this?

Is there a way to get YouTube to fully buffer still?

Comment: See this - http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/26213/youtube-stops-buffering-when-video-is-paused

Answer (score 1):

Of course, it saves bandwidth. For movies and music this isn't handy, but that's not the average content Youtube is serving.