# Is there a way to force buffering on YouTube?

Tags: youtube, video-streaming

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [YouTube stops buffering when video is paused](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/26213/youtube-stops-buffering-when-video-is-paused)

A couple of months ago, YouTube introduced some über-intelligent solution which determines if the user is idle or not, and stops buffering after some time while the video is paused.

This is horrible at time. I don't like when the video stops suddenly and needs to fill up the buffer. However I can't find a way to force pre-buffering. YouTube just buffers something like 1 minute in advance, and if my connection is slower than usual, I can't watch video all-in-once.

In the past, I could just open a YouTube video, pause it and wait until it's fully loaded (I prefer heavy multi-tab internet browsing, so it was not a problem for me to do it that way).

Is there any solution to force the pre-buffering on YouTube now?

Comment: However, sadly, there is no fully satisfactory answer there that will work for all videos and without a need to have YouTube account.